# pillow installation error in vs when using djngo

Tags: python

ERRORS:
core.Item.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "pip install Pillow".

since I was installed pillow
when I run the pip install pillow command It shows the requirement already satisfied.
please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because you have PIL and Pillow installed. Pillow is a fork of PIL and is the maintained library. It is recommended not to use PIL because it has become outdated. Here are the steps to fix the problem:

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip uninstall pillow
```

then:

```
pip install pillow
```

If this doesn't solve the problem, go into your python site-packages or dist-packages and remove any files or folders related to PIL or pillow, then:

```
pip install pillow
```

Comment: sorry it's not working any other suggestions

Comment: Try downloading the wheel file from pypi and installing via pip